# SPA router link show two pages

Tags: npm, hyperlink, single-page-application, router, svelte

I am new with svelte and npm. I am triying to do my first app. I executed npx degit... npm install and npm install svete-spa-router --save.

My page is ok, but when I do click on ref link, my current page is still showed and under it show the page of the link. What am I doing wrong?.

Next my routes.js code:

```
import Inicio from './componentes/Inicio.svelte'
import Login from './componentes/Login.svelte'
import Registro from './componentes/Registro.svelte'
import Nosotros from './componentes/Nosotros.svelte'
import Blog from './componentes/Blog1.svelte'
import ErrorRuta from './componentes/ErrorRuta.svelte'

const routes = {
    '/':Inicio,
    '/Login':Login,
    '/Registro':Registro,
    '/Nosotros':Nosotros,
    '/Blog':Blog,
    '*':ErrorRuta
}

export default routes
```

Next my App.svelte code:

```
<script>
    import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'  
    import {link} from 'svelte-spa-router'
    import routes from './routes'
</script>
  
<header class="site-header inicio">
    <div class="contenedor contenido-header">
      <div class="barra">
            <a href="/" use:link>
                <img class="cabecera" src="./img/Logo.jpg" alt="Logotipo">
            </a>
        
            <nav id="navegacion" class="navegacion">
                <a href="/Login" use:link>Login</a>
                <a href="/Registro" use:link>Registro</a>
                <a href="/Nosotros" use:link>Nosotros</a>
                <a href="/Blog" use:link>Blog</a>
            </nav>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</header>  
  

  <main class="contenedor seccion">
    
    <h2 class="font-weight300 centrar-texto">Servicios ofrecidos</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-anuncios">
        <div class="anuncio">
            <img class="centrada" src="img/finanzas.jpg" alt="Imagen finanzas">
            <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                <h3 class="centrado">Robot EA ZigZag coberturas</h3>
                <br/>
                <p>Es importante contar con nociones básicas de trading y de MetaTrader 4 para operarlo. El robot EA ZigZag Coberturas se basa en el indicador ZigZag y cruce de medias para determinar la apertura de posiciones en el par de divisas en que se encuentre trabajando. Cuando la operación llega a un cierto nivel de Stop Loss, el robot activa coberturas y las administra, de tal forma que no haya pérdida, o la pérdida sea mínima.</p>
                <br/>
                <p>El objetivo del robot EA ZigZag coberturas, es proteger el capital, principalmente, de las variaciones drásticas y manipulaciones del mercado.</p>
                <br/>
                <p>Como todo robot, es imperativo que siempre se encuentre en línea y operando, para poder cumplir su propósito.</p>
                  
                
                <a href="/" use:link class="boton boton-azul d-block">Descargar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="anuncio">
            <img class="centrada" src="img/finanzas2.jpg" alt="Imagen finanzas2">
            <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                <h3 class="centrado">Servicios</h3>
                <br/>
                <p>Únete a nuestro canal de Telegram para compartir ideas de Trading.</p>
                <br/>
                <p>Participa en nuestro Blog para discutir estrategias que puedan ayudar a todos a alcanzar mejores resultados en el Trading.</p>
                <br/>
                <p>Participar no es gratis. El costo es que, de tus ganancias, destines un porcentaje (que tu decidas) a algún horfanato, asilo de ancianos (el que tu decidas).</p>
                                
                <a href="/Blog" use:link class="boton boton-azul d-block">Ir al Blog</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
  
<Router {routes} />

<footer class="blue page-footer">
    <div class="footer-copyright">
        <div class="container">
             © 2021 Copyright 
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

App.svelte only should to have next code:

import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'
    import routes from './routes'

<Router {routes} />